# getopt, optarg and optional parameters

Tags: c, gcc, getopt

This question specifically concerns getopt for optional arguments in gcc.  When an option is defined as having an optional argument and no argument is given, is optarg set to  a null pointer or a pointer to an empty string. The manual does not seem to deal with this case. Is the behaviour guaranteed?

Barry

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Be aware that GCC is a C compiler and you could be linking with different implementations of the `getopt()` function on different systems. For example, if you use GCC on Solaris, you will probably be using the Solaris implementation of `getopt()`, which is rather powerful when you write your code to use the CLIP (Command Line Interface Paradigm) extensions, but that is close to POSIX `getopt()` when you don't, whereas on Linux, you will probably be using the GLIBC implementation of `getopt()` which has a different set of extensions.

Comment: **Thanks** for all your help, that was very informative. I am reviewing somebody else's 17 year old code which now seems to mirror POSIX getopt, without using the library. I will look more closely and give the matter further consideration.

Answer (score 3):

`getopt` with optional arguments is an implementation-defined extension of the POSIX function. If it is not stated in the documentation how it behaves, an explicit check for `optarg == NULL` is safest. If it is not `NULL`, I personally wouldn't imagine that an empty string would denote the lack of an argument, but it could.

My own implementation sets `optarg` to `NULL` when no argument is detected, but it could just as easily point to the memory address of a static object containing a 0 byte as the first byte read such as `char noarg = 0;` in the source file for the `getopt` function. Incidentally, the GNU libc implementation also sets it to `NULL` without documenting the behavior currently.

If you wanted to be safe in the event of either behavior, especially due to the lack of documentation, I suggest doing the following:

```
if (optarg && *optarg) {
    /* Argument present */
}
else {
    /* No argument */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go by the POSIX [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) definition, then the behaviour is defined:

> If it detects a missing option-argument, it shall return the `<colon>` character (`':'`) if the first character of optstring was a `<colon>`, or a `<question-mark>` character (`'?'`) otherwise.

Note that the only time a missing option argument can be detected is when the last argument is one of the valid option characters and there is no extra argument to be the missing argument.  This means you can only have one missing argument in any invocation of any command (which is pretty useless, really).

If you use GNU [`getopt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt), then the rules are similar, but different in detail:

> An option character in this string can be followed by a colon (`‘:’`) to indicate that it takes a required argument. If an option character is followed by two colons (`‘::’`), its argument is optional; this is a GNU extension.
>
> `getopt` has three ways to deal with options that follow non-options argv elements. The special argument `‘--’` forces in all cases the end of option scanning.

This is an over-statement, IIRC.  If the `-f` option takes an argument, writing `-f --` gives you an option argument of `--`.

> - The default is to permute the contents of `argv` while scanning it so that eventually all the non-options are at the end. This allows options to be given in any order, even with programs that were not written to expect this.
> - If the options argument string begins with a hyphen (`‘-’`), this is treated specially. It permits arguments that are not options to be returned as if they were associated with option character `‘\1’`.
> - POSIX demands the following behavior: The first non-option stops option processing. This mode is selected by either setting the environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT or beginning the options argument string with a plus sign (`‘+’`).
>
> The `getopt` function returns the option character for the next command line option. When no more option arguments are available, it returns -1. There may still be more non-option arguments; you must compare the external variable `optind` against the `argc` parameter to check this.
>
> If the option has an argument, `getopt` returns the argument by storing it in the variable `optarg`. You don't ordinarily need to copy the `optarg` string, since it is a pointer into the original `argv` array, not into a static area that might be overwritten.
>
> If `getopt` finds an option character in `argv` that was not included in `options`, or a missing option argument, it returns `‘?’` and sets the external variable `optopt` to the actual option character. If the first character of options is a colon (`‘:’`), then `getopt` returns `‘:’` instead of `‘?’` to indicate a missing option argument. In addition, if the external variable `opterr` is nonzero (which is the default), `getopt` prints an error message.

This says that you need to look at the return value from `getopt()` and set the first character of the option string to `:` to know when an argument is missing.  Again, my recollection is that you end up only being able to have one optional argument, but it is several years since I last did any extensive checking of system-provided variants of `getopt()`.